# gdal_translate of KMLSUPEROVERLAY issues making nodata transparent

Tags: geotiff-tiff, kml, gdal-translate, kmz, nodata

I'm trying to use gdal to make a superoverlay KML / KMZ from a single band .tif (GTiff / GeoTIFF) which I created in ArcGIS. I want the nodata region to be transparent, but it has been showing up as white and a different raster value has become transparent.

Below is a link to download the .tif and the full gdalinfo for the .tif as well. The nodata for the .tif is set to -128, but it has been appearing as white (png pixel value 255,255,255) in the KMZ superoverlay. This is the case even when I change the nodata value to something else, like zero. Regardless, the .tif raster value of 1 *has* been turned transparent in the KMZ (png pixel value 0,0,0), though I would prefer it was not transparent.

Here is the command I've used to produce the KMZ pictured:

`gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -scale -co format=png -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY TestRaster1.tif test1.kmz`

I've referenced other posts about issues getting gdal_translate KMLSUPEROVERLAY to make nodata values transparent, but have not had success yet. I have not found anything about the wrong raster value becoming transparent.

Link to the download the raster:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rzMXE5RvB0rPWG17ejorqoi_1P-jiyw5?usp=sharing

gdalinfo TestRaster1.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: TestRaster1.tif
       TestRaster1.tif.aux.xml
Size is 1022, 768
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4269]],
    CONVERSION["Albers Equal Area",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (881456.543850616551936,1239668.893288560211658)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  881456.544, 1239668.893) ( 86d23'33.03"W, 33d49'18.85"N)
Lower Left  (  881456.544, 1231988.893) ( 86d24' 3.37"W, 33d45'12.65"N)
Upper Right (  891676.544, 1239668.893) ( 86d16'54.79"W, 33d48'45.43"N)
Lower Right (  891676.544, 1231988.893) ( 86d17'25.47"W, 33d44'39.26"N)
Center      (  886566.544, 1235828.893) ( 86d20'29.16"W, 33d46'59.10"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=46.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=46.000, Mean=4.747, StdDev=4.167
  NoData Value=-128
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=46
    STATISTICS_MEAN=4.7473687784342
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=4.1672481743036
  Image Structure Metadata:
    PIXELTYPE=SIGNEDBYTE
```

[image: TestRaster1 KMLSUPEROVERLAY test1.kmz]